# Pre and post numbers

Tags: depth-first-search, directed-graph

When doing a `depth first search` on a `Directed Graph` what is meant by `pre` and `post` numbers?

For example:

[image]

If you were to start at node `A` and do an alphabetic `Depth First Search` how do you determine the pre and post numbers?

Comment: Using your diagram there is no link FROM node A, so you are already done and perhaps pre = post = null?

Comment: @Marichyasana I dont think so. The question I'm asked says to start at `A` and give pre and post numbers for each of the nodes.

Answer (score 5):

Note : Although the question has been asked quite a time ago, but it may be referred by someone else.

Pre and Post values in a Depth First Search depict the start time of the visit and end time of visit of a vertex respectively. By start time, I mean the time when the vertex is discovered and end time means the time when all the children (in the DFS tree) will be visited.

Here's a sample pseudocode for DFS-

```
dfs(Graph, Vertex)

    static count = 1
    pre[Vertex] = count++
    visited[Vertex] = true

    for all v in Edge(Vertex, v)
        if visited[v] = false
            dfs(Graph, v)

    post[Vertex] = count++;
```

The pre and post values have a lot of significance. Edge classification is one such example. Also you can find the use of post values where sources and sinks come into picture.